# confluent-kafka-python json_producer : Unrecognized field: schemaType

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

have encountered this error `"Unrecognized field: schemaType (HTTP status code 422, SR code 422)"` when i execute a json_producer.py example in Confluent Github repository

this is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    postgres:
        container_name: postgres
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=shipment_db
            - PGPASSWORD=password
        image: 'debezium/postgres:13'

    zookeeper:
        container_name: zookeeper
        ports:
            - '2181:2181'
            - '2888:2888'
            - '3888:3888'
        image: 'debezium/zookeeper:1.7'

    kafka:
        container_name: kafka
        ports:
            - '9092:9092'
        links:
            - 'zookeeper:zookeeper'
        image: 'debezium/kafka:1.7'
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        #volumes:
        #    - ./kafka:/kafka/config:rw

    connect:
        image: debezium/connect:1.7
        hostname: connect
        container_name: connect
        ports:
            - 8083:8083
        environment:
            BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
            GROUP_ID: 1
            CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
            OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
            STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_statuses
            CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
            CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-cluster-A
            CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /kafka/data, /kafka/connect
            #EXTERNAL_LIBS_DIR: /kafka/external_libs,/kafka/data
            CLASSPATH: /kafka/data/*
            KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR: /kafka/data, /kafka/connect
            #CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect=DEBUG,org.apache.plc4x.kafka.Plc4xSinkConnector=DEBUG"

        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./plugins
              target: /kafka/data
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
            - kafka
            - postgres
        links:
            - zookeeper
            - kafka
            - postgres

    schema-registry:
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.4.6
        hostname: schema-registry
        container_name: schema-registry
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
            - kafka
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
        environment:
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8081"

    ksqldb-server:
        image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.23.1
        hostname: ksqldb-server
        container_name: ksqldb-server
        depends_on:
            - kafka
            - zookeeper
            - schema-registry
        ports:
            - "8088:8088"
        volumes:
            - "./confluent-hub-components/:/usr/share/kafka/plugins/"
        environment:
            KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
            KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
            KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
            KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
            KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
            KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: http://connect:8083
```

the code of json_producer is [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/json_producer.py) in the repository.

The error appear when i execute this command:

`$ python3 json_producer.py -b 0.0.0.0:9092 -s http://0.0.0.0:8081 -t test`

and the stacktrace is the following:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alessio/fm_v2/python/confluent-kafka-python-master/examples/venv_examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/serializing_producer.py", line 172, in produce
    value = self._value_serializer(value, ctx)
  File "/home/alessio/fm_v2/python/confluent-kafka-python-master/examples/venv_examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/json_schema.py", line 190, in __call__
    self._schema_id = self._registry.register_schema(subject,
  File "/home/alessio/fm_v2/python/confluent-kafka-python-master/examples/venv_examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/schema_registry_client.py", line 336, in register_schema
    response = self._rest_client.post(
  File "/home/alessio/fm_v2/python/confluent-kafka-python-master/examples/venv_examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/schema_registry_client.py", line 127, in post
    return self.send_request(url, method='POST', body=body)
  File "/home/alessio/fm_v2/python/confluent-kafka-python-master/examples/venv_examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/schema_registry_client.py", line 174, in send_request
    raise SchemaRegistryError(response.status_code,
confluent_kafka.schema_registry.error.SchemaRegistryError: Unrecognized field: schemaType (HTTP status code 422, SR code 422)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_producer.py", line 172, in <module>
    main(parser.parse_args())
  File "json_producer.py", line 151, in main
    producer.produce(topic=topic, key=str(uuid4()), value=user,
  File "/home/alessio/fm_v2/python/confluent-kafka-python-master/examples/venv_examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/serializing_producer.py", line 174, in produce
    raise ValueSerializationError(se)
confluent_kafka.error.ValueSerializationError: KafkaError{code=_VALUE_SERIALIZATION,val=-161,str="Unrecognized field: schemaType (HTTP status code 422, SR code 422)"}
```

where is the problem? Thanks for any reply.

Comment: I don't know about the error exactly, but 0.0.0.0 isn't a proper address for Kafka or the registry... Also, you should try the newest version of the registry that actually supports Jsonschema. Otherwise, if you've not modified anything in the code, you should make a github issue instead

Comment: the version of schema-registry is the last (5.4.0) and for the address is irrilevant.. i have tryed with localhost but the result is the same. The code is original.. i will make an issue on gitlab. Thanks

Comment: Except the version does matter. Jsonschema support was not added until version 6.0 and the latest is 7.0.1... I don't understand why you specifically need 5.4.6?

Comment: Is my error.. i have thinked that the last is 5.4.6 and not 7.0.1.

Comment: Okay... So, do you get the same error with at least version 6.0.0 of the registry? Or anything newer that includes other bug fixes?

Comment: it works! with the version 6.0.0 of schema registry the json_producer send the data correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsonschema support was not added to the Confluent Schema Registry until version 6.0, and this is why the error reports issues about a `schemaType` field, because any lower versions of the Registry response/request payload do not know about that field.

Upgrading to at least that version, or using the latest version of the image will solve that error

If you just want to produce JSON, then you don't need the Registry. More details at https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/ .
You can use the regular `producer.py` example and provide JSON objects *as strings* on the CLI